# How to speed up numpy array-filling in python?

Tags: python, optimization, numpy

I'm trying to fill a preallocated bytearray using the following code:

```
# preallocate a block array
dt = numpy.dtype('u8')
in_memory_blocks = numpy.zeros(_AVAIL_IN_MEMORY_BLOCKS, dt)

...

# write all the blocks out, flushing only as desired
blocks_per_flush_xrange = xrange(0, blocks_per_flush)
for _ in xrange(0, num_flushes):
    for block_index in blocks_per_flush_xrange:
        in_memory_blocks[block_index] = random.randint(0, _BLOCK_MAX)

    print('flushing bytes stored in memory...')

    # commented out for SO; exists in actual code
    # removing this doesn't make an order-of-magnitude difference in time
    # m.update(in_memory_blocks[:blocks_per_flush])

    in_memory_blocks[:blocks_per_flush].tofile(f)
```

Some points:

- `num_flushes` is low, at around 4 - 10
- `blocks_per_flush` is a large number, on the order of millions
- `in_memory_blocks` can be a fairly large buffer (I've set it as low as 1MB and as high as 100MB) but the timing is very consitent...
- `_BLOCK_MAX` is the max for an 8-byte unsigned int
- `m` is a `hashilib.md5()`

Generating 1MB using the above code takes ~1s; 500MB takes ~376s. By comparison, my simple C program that uses rand() can create a 500MB file in 8s.

How can I improve the performance in the above loop? I'm pretty sure I'm ignoring something obvious that's causing this massive difference in runtime.

Comment: iterating over arbitrary types (python) like this is extremely slow compared to compiled type-specific iterators (internal to numpy).  If you want an array of random integers like you do in your example, use the `numpy.random.randint` function.  But I suspect this is just for illustrative purposes.  You'll need to post what you are actually filling your array with to get more specific help.

Comment: No, I really am creating random data and computing a checksum over it. I thought the memory allocation was the bottleneck, not the iteration. I can imagine that the internal numpy iterators would be faster (given that the underlying C implementation would be using pointer arithmetic).

Comment: Please, clarify: is `_BLOCK_MAX` equal to `255` or `9223372036854775807` and whether `dt` is equal to `numpy.uint8` or `numpy.uint64`?

Comment: To clarify: my code had `dt` as `numpy.uint64` and `_BLOCK_MAX` as the upper bound for `uint64`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're allocating contiguous blocks, you should be able to do the following (getting rid of the inner loop entirely):

```
for _ in xrange(0, num_flushes):
    in_memory_blocks[:blocks_per_flush] = numpy.random.randint(
            0, _BLOCK_MAX+1, blocks_per_flush)

    print('flushing bytes stored in memory...')

    # commented out for SO; exists in actual code
    # removing this doesn't make an order-of-magnitude difference in time
    # m.update(in_memory_blocks[:blocks_per_flush])

    in_memory_blocks[:blocks_per_flush].tofile(f)
```

This uses the `numpy.random.randint` function which allocates a whole block of memory and fills it with random integers (note J.F. Sebastian's comment below about `numpy.random.randint` versus `random.randint`). There's no way (as far as I can see) to fill a preallocated array using the numpy random routines. The other problem is that numpy's randint returns int64 arrays. If you need integers of some other size then you can use the numpy typing methods, for example numpy.uint8. If you want randints to cover the whole range of the type, then [@J. F. Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683136/how-to-speed-up-numpy-array-filling-in-python/5685025#5685025)'s method below using numpy.random.bytes is going to be the best (in almost any case!).

However, simple tests show reasonable times (of the same order of magnitude as the C code). The following code tests the time to allocate uint8 arrays of 20,000,000 random integers using the numpy method:

```
from timeit import Timer
t = Timer(stmt='a=numpy.uint8(numpy.random.randint(0, 100, 20000000))',
        setup='import numpy')
test_runs = 50
time = t.timeit(test_runs)/test_runs
print time
```

I get it taking about 0.7 seconds per allocation on my 4 year old Core2 laptop (it runs 50 times so it'll take longer to run the whole test). That's 0.7 s per allocation of 20,000,000 random uint8 integers, so I'd expect something around 20s for the whole 500MB.

More memory would mean you could allocate bigger chunks at once, but you're still effectively wasting time allocating and writing 64 bits for each int when you only need 8 (I haven't quantified this effect). If its still not fast enough, you could call your C implementation using the numpy ctypes interface. This is really rather easy to use and you'd get virtually no slowdown over pure C.

The general take home message is that with numpy, always try to use the numpy routines where they exist, remembering that falling back to C with ctypes is not too painful. In general, this methodology allows really quite effective use of python with very little slowdown for numerical processing.

**Edit:** Something else that just occurred to me: as its implemented above, I think you'd be making an additional unnecessary copy. If `in_memory_blocks` is of length `blocks_per_flush`, then you'd do better just to assign it the return from `numpy.random.randint`, rather than allocate it to a certain subarray (which in the general case *must* be a copy). So:

```
in_memory_blocks = numpy.random.randint(0, _BLOCK_MAX+1, blocks_per_flush)
```

rather than:

```
in_memory_blocks[:blocks_per_flush] = numpy.random.randint(
        0, _BLOCK_MAX+1, blocks_per_flush)
```

However, having timed this, the first case doesn't lead to a significant increase in speed (only about 2%), so its probably not worth worrying about too much. I guess the overwhelming amount of time is spent actually generating random numbers (which is what I would expect).

Comment: Doing this led to a dramatic speedup. Previously I was looking at ~1MB/sec. With this change I can generate ~258MB/sec. I had noticed the `numpy.random.randint function` but skipped over it because I had the mistaken assumption that it was the memory allocation that was the major performance hit.

Comment: `numpy.random.randint()` (half-open interval) differs from `random.randint()` (closed interval: both ends included). Use `numpy.random.random_integers()`.

Comment: `numpy.dtype('u8')` is `numpy.dtype('uint64')`; it is not `numpy.dtype('uint8')`

Comment: My mistake, I assumed they were the same, I'll add clarification.

Comment: I had already removed the copy in my implementation (i.e. when I coded it I used `in_memory_blocks = numpy.random.randint(0, _BLOCK_MAX, blocks_per_flush)`). Since `numpy.random.randint(...)` returned a new buffer I saw no reason to copy it to `in_memory_blocks`.

Answer (score 7):

Due to the fact that `0.._BLOCK_MAX` covers all the possible values for `numpy.uint8` (I assume that `numpy.dtype('u8')` (i.e., `numpy.uint64` is a typo) you could use:

```
import numpy as np

for _ in xrange(0, num_flushes):
    in_memory_blocks = np.frombuffer(np.random.bytes(blocks_per_flush),
                                     dtype=np.uint8)

    print('flushing bytes stored in memory...')
    # ...
```

This variant ~8 times faster than [@hgomersall's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683136/how-to-speed-up-numpy-array-filling-in-python/5683426#5683426):

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'import numpy as np' '
>     np.uint8(np.random.randint(0,256,20000000))'
10 loops, best of 3: 316 msec per loop

$ python -mtimeit -s'import numpy as np' '
>     np.frombuffer(np.random.bytes(20000000), dtype=np.uint8)'
10 loops, best of 3: 38.6 msec per loop
```

If `numpy.dtype('u8')` is not a typo and you indeed require `numpy.uint64` then:

```
a = np.int64(np.random.random_integers(0, _BLOCK_MAX, blocks_per_flush))
in_memory_blocks = a.view(np.uint64) # unsigned
```

Note: `np.int64()` doesn't make a copy if the array's dtype is already `np.int64`. `.view(numpy.uint64)` forces its interpretation as unsigned (also no copy is performed).

Comment: I have a requirement to perform (at minimum) `n` writes to disk.

Comment: Won't #1 (using `np.random.randint(...)`) actually return 4 - 8 times as many bytes (depending on the default int type on your machine) than #2? For example, I could naively imagine implementing np.random.bytes by generating `int(num_bytes_requested/unsigned_int_size)` rand-ints + filling in the remainder bytes however you want. This could explain the difference in performance.

Comment: @Allen George: I use `np.random.bytes()` only for `dtype=np.uint8` case and yes `np.uint8(np.random.randint(0,256,20000000))` temporary creates 4-8 times larger array than necessary in this case. For `dtype=np.uint64` use `np.int64(np.random.random_integers(0, _BLOCK_MAX, blocks_per_flush)).view(np.uint64)`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I cannot find the documentation for `np.uint8()`: do you have a reference?  I see it converts a sequence (and maybe an array) to an array of dtype uint8, but it would be nice to know this is documented, and therefore a stable feature.

Comment: @EOL: `np.uint8` behaves the same as other dtype-types in numpy. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to fill a file, block_size bytes at a time, this may be faster than the previous answers.  Based on generators and completely bypassing array creation:

```
import numpy as np

def random_block_generator(block_size):
    while True:
        yield np.random.bytes(block_size)

rbg = random_block_generator(BLOCK_SIZE)
```

Then your usage is:

```
f = open('testfile.bin','wb')

for _ in xrange(blocks_to_write):
    f.write( rbg.next())

f.close()
```

Numpy uses deterministic random number generation (the next number in the sequence is always the same, it just starts in a random place when it initializes).  If you need true random data (cryptography grade), then you can use `import Crypto.Random as cr` and `yield cr.get_random_bytes(block_size)` instead of np.

Also, if your BLOCK_SIZE is a defined constant you can use a generator expression like this (using the Crypto library this time):

```
import Crypto.Random as cr
from itertools import repeat

BLOCK_SIZE = 1000

rbg = (cr.get_random_bytes(BLOCK_SIZE) for _ in repeat(0))

f = open('testfile.bin','wb')

for _ in xrange(blocks_to_write):
    f.write( rbg.next())

f.close()
```

That includes the implementation `rbg=...` and the execution.  This generator method, even with the slightly slower Crypto.Random, will max out from disk i/o long before it maxes computation (although I'm sure the other answers do too).

UPDATE:

Some timing data on an Athlon X2 245 --

- Crypto: Generate 500MB, don't write -- 10.8s (46 MB/s)
- Crypto: Generate 500MB and write -- 11.2s (44.5 MB/s)
- Numpy: Generate 500MB, don't write -- 1.4s (360 MB/s)
- Numpy: Generate 500MB, and write -- 7.1s ( 70 MB/s)

So the numpy version is about 8x faster (easily fast enough to max my old platter drive).  I tested both of them using the generator expression form, rather than the generator function form.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not very good at optimization, but I don't see a way your code could run faster. You're using purely iterators, and a O(1) access structure.

The problem, I think, is your language of choice. Remember you're running in a virtual machine, and an interpreter at that. Your C program will always run an order of magnitude faster.

Comment: Using the NumPy package in Python is actually fast: time consuming operations are done through compiled code. So, a C program and a Python program using NumPy can have similar running times. It is true that the Python version is slower, though (sometimes not by much), and that it can be *much* slower (for instance if fast NumPy array operations are not used). On the other hand, I have seen Python programs run faster than Fortran ones because the Fortran program unnecessarily preallocated huge arrays, "just in case" there was a lot of data to process.